# SSRS grouping columns to toggle visibility

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with several columns - 3 of the columns had visibility set such that it could be toggled by a particular cell. The report was a single tablix with headings at the top and row groups set up below those headings. My toggle item was in the headings - i.e. outside any row groups. There are no column groups - I just want to be able to hide a few columns on demand. It worked fine but...

When a new requirement arose to throw a page within one of the groups, I had to move the headings such that they were within the highest level group. Since then I continue to get the error message:

*"Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a parent"*

I have tried removing the toggle and starting again from scratch but I continue to get the message. I have also tried viewing the XML in case there is any stray toggle logic hanging around but it appears not. Any suggestions as to how I might resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is to add a new row at the very top of the tablix outside any groups and immediately above the headings (themselves within a group) and put the toggle textbox in that row. That seemed to do the trick (for Excel output anyway).